# How I can fix MAC error in asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application all things are working fine but after some minutes when I click on a button it gives me this error :

> **Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web
>   Farm or cluster, ensure that
>    configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used
>   in a cluster.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.**
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Web.HttpException: Validation
>   of viewstate MAC failed. If this
>   application is hosted by a Web Farm or
>   cluster, ensure that 
>   configuration specifies the same
>   validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used
>   in a cluster.

How I can resolve this ?

Comment: it occours in the default.aspx page I have used session and viewstate is enable because I used a lot of asp.net componant

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx - Have you gone through description and solution provided here?

Comment: GridView, my page is heavy and I used web form in all pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post covers this in quite a bit of detail:
http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f15/fix-validation-viewstate-mac-failed-6085/

In the past i've used this method:

```
  <system.web>
  <pages enableViewStateMac="false" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: *DO NOT DO THIS* In doing so you've removed all protection for values stored in viewstate. Far better to actually figure out what the problem is, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

setting enableviewstatemac  to false means if the encoded view state changes your view state won't be replaced with the older one, this can be a security issues. instead of this, after seeing your error put a persistence machine key in web.config if you are in web farm scenario because dynamically generated machine key tends to view_state error.